# interpretation of eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix. An eigendecomposition of $A$ produces $A$ = $W V W^T$, where $W$ is $A$'s corresponding eigenvector matrix and $W$ is $A$'s corresponding (diagonal) eigenvector matrix.
Is there an interpretation of $WV$? Also, is there an interpretation of $WVZ$ for some $Z$ that's not equal to $W^T$?

Comment: What do you mean by "an interpretation"?

Comment: The columns of $W$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. The columns of $WV$ are the eigenvectors scaled by their corresponding eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation that, in the basis formed by the eigenvectors ( the columns of the matrix $W$), is represented by scale transformations of these vectors, with scale factors that are the eigenvalues  in the diagonal of the matrix $V$.

In other words: the eigenvectors form a basis of the vector space in which the matrix acts as a linear transformation, end in this basis the action of the linear transformation on a vectos $v$ expressed as a linear combination of the vectors of this basisis, is given by the same linear combination of the products of the eigenvalues with the corresponding eigenvectors.